# JQuery is not redirecting after successful AJAX call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I searched all the questions on here and tried the answers, but my script is not redirecting after completing the AJAX call. The post submission is successfully submitting, the only issue is the redirect. Please help! Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('.renail-btn').click( function(e) {
        var ajax_url = jQuery(this).data('ajax');
        var postid = jQuery(this).data('postid');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : ajax_url,
            type: 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'man_duplicate_post',
                post : postid
            },
            dataType: JSON,
            success : function( data ) {
                var jsData = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(jsData.redirect);
                if( jsData.error ) {
                    alert(jsData.error_msg);
                }
                window.location = jsData.redirect;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

The data from Chrome Dev tools shows the following after the JSON parse...

```
{error: false, error_msg: "0", redirect:"http://staging.mysite.com/2016/10/09/old-logo-2-2-23/"}
error:false
error_msg:"0"
redirect:"http://staging.mysite.com/2016/10/09/old-logo-2-2-23/"
```

I've tried using window.location, window.location.href, with and without return false, without using json data, and using [''] instead of dot notation on the data... I'm sure it's something simple, but I haven't yet figured it out.

Comment: try location.href="....."

Comment: Still no response with location.href

Comment: Behalf the other error you are facing you need to pass this as a string: dataType: 'json',

Comment: Remove also this: `return false;` please

Comment: When I do that (dataType change), I get this error in the console... Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Removed `return false;` but nothing changes

Comment: Normally if you are getting the data from a `php` file you will do echo json_encode(<---the result---->) so I don't see any reason why you are using `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: As you're always redirecting in the success function, why are you doing an ajax request, you might as well just use a regular form ?

Comment: @twolf Have you verified that `jsData.redirect` is a valid URL and the `window.location = ...` line is actually being reached?

Comment: @Franco... You da man! Once I removed the parse AND updated the dataType it finally worked correctly! Left it as `location.href` too... Thanks!

Comment: Do You mind I put this in an answer so you can accept it? It will be useful for others having for the same issue

Comment: Yeah. Put it up there and I'll accept it!